# Trying to organize files by extension using a script (grep, for, foreach, find), but I'm overwhelmed. Looking for advice

Tags: grep, find

I want to iterate through all files in the Source directory and stick them into the Dest directory.

Example list of files:

```
/source/folder/text.txt
/source/folder/document.pdf
/source/folder/that/is/deeper/picture.jpg
/source/folder/picture2.JPG
```

After the script is run, I'd like the dest folder to look like:

```
/dest/folder/txt/text.txt
/dest/folder/pdf/document.pdf
/dest/folder/jpg/picture1.jpg
/dest/folder/jpg/picture2.JPG
```

I've learned I can chain `-exec` commands on the back of `find`, but I don't think that's what I want.

`grep` might be useful, but since it's a one-liner, I think writing it will be complex.

A forloop seems to be the best way, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to extract the file name.

```
SOURCE=/my/source/dir/

for f in $SOURCE
do
  echo $f
done
```

$f appears to be only the directory and does not list the actual file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#this script sorts files according to their extensions
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
(find . -type f) > /tmp/temp
for var in `cat /tmp/temp`
do
    name=`basename "$var"` ext=`echo $name | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2-`
    mkdir -p $ext
    mv "$var" $ext/ 2> /dev/null
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

this script will not sort files without extension

Comment: It is a bit hidden in the question, but apart from sorting, OP wants to *move* the files to (newly created?) folders, like in the (imo) duplicate, asked by Kasiya.

Comment: @JacobVlijm this script will move abc.jpg to jpg folder and so on for other file extensions

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that